# Can a rule in Outlook kick off a macro?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

Is it possible to kick off a macro from a set of rules.  For example: I have a rule that moves all emails not in my contacts to an 'Unknown' folder.  I would then like to execute a macro that clears all 'trash' and 'deleted' emails.

Comment: [How to create a script for the Rules Wizard in Outlook - Office | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/create-script-for-rule-wizard-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with David, you could refer to the official documentation to create a script for the rule in Outlook. Besides, here is one article about emptying multiple deleted items folders for your reference, hope it's helpful to you: **https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/empty-multiple-deleted-items-folders-using-a-macro/**